# Reach Listbox count from module

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am trying to get the total count of form1.listbox1 items count by calling from inside the module

```
MsgBox(Form1.ListBox1.Items.Count.ToString)
```

Value is always display as zero

Note : This listbox is loaded at runtime and if i load any items at design time then the count is displayed correctly...Appreciate your help

Comment: Can you show where you initialize `Form1`? There is no global access to forms (apart from `Application.OpenForms`) so you need an instance of it in the module. You cannot simply create one by using `Dim Form1 = New Form1()`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - It's initialized at load event     

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        ListBox1.Items.AddRange(Array)
        StartProxy()
End Sub

Comment: You have misundertood me or i have misunderstood you. _"I  am trying to get the total count of form1.listbox1 items count by calling from inside the module"_ That sounds as if you are trying that in a module and not in the `Form`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Yes I am trying that in a module

Comment: I am guessing you dont load the items manually Form1.ListBox1.Items.add(something) but through some type of binding source. If so, you need to get the count from your binding source, not the control.

Comment: Are you reading my comments at all? Where is it initialized then? From where do you get `Form1`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter - But inside the module I am having Loop

For my_index As Integer = 0 To Form.ListBox1.Items.Count - 1

Comment: But where is `Form` or `Form1` initialized? You cannot access an instance variable from a different object without that instance.

Comment: most likely `Form1` is just the class, not the runtime instance, so the items count will always be zero. the code needs to reference the *instance* which is why you are being asked where/how/when the form is initialized

Comment: I am sorry i am very new to .net...Form1 is a form and I am trying to call that Form1.listbox1 from Module1